# how to convert nested loops with body to parallelized iterables for multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

i have the below two nested loops. i want to use them as iterables passed to .map operator to parallelize their execution.i am familiar with the following notation:

```
with PoolExec(max_workers=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['proceses_count']),initializer=self.initPool,initargs=(arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7,arg8,arg9,)) as GridCells10mX10mIteratorPool.__poolExec:
        self.__chunkSize = PoolUtils.getChunkSizeForLenOfIterables(lenOfIterablesList=self.__maxNumOfCellsVertically*self.__maxNumOfCellsHorizontally,cpuCount=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['cpu_count']))
        for res in GridCells10mX10mIteratorPool.__poolExec.map(self.run,[(i,j) for i in range(0,1800,10) for j in range(0,2000,10)] ,chunksize=self.__chunkSize):
```

but as shown in code below, there are two lines of code after the outer loop and another two lines of code after the inner one.how can i convert these two loop to the above mentioned notation

**code**:

```
for x in range(row,row + gVerticalStep):
        if rowsCnt == gVerticalStep:
            rowsCnt = 0
        for y in range(col,col + gHorizontalStep):
            if colsCnt == gHorizontalStep:
                colsCnt = 0
```

Comment: Is colsCnt and rowsCnt the input data?

Comment: @Alexander they are defined before the outer loop and set to zero

Comment: But are they the parameters you want to feed to the map function?

Comment: @Alexander yes please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple means to turn nested loops into an iterable is to create a generator function.  To use your code as an example it could look something like this.

```
def param_iterator(row, col, gVerticalStep):
    rowsCnt = colsCnt = 0
    for x in range(row,row + gVerticalStep):
        if rowsCnt == gVerticalStep:
            rowsCnt = 0
        for y in range(col,col + gHorizontalStep):
            if colsCnt == gHorizontalStep:
                colsCnt = 0
            yield (x, y, rowsCnt, colsCnt)


with PoolExec(...) as poolExec:
    params = param_iterator()
    poolExec.map(self.run, params):
```

Comment: thanks, but also x and y are input to self.run..would you please modify the code?

Comment: Sure thing...  You will want to double check the parameters are in the correct order though

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to convert a double (or triple) `for` loop into a single `iterable`, you can use the `itertools` library.

Specifically, `itertools.product()` ([documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)), will stick two iterables into a single one.

For example, the following code snippet:

```py
for x in range(1, 5):
    for y in range(1, 5):
        print((x,y))
```

will do the same thing as this

```py
import itertools

iterable = itertools.product(range(1,5), range(1,5))
for x,y in iterable:
    print((x,y))
```

The notable difference though, is that now you have both for loops as a single iterable which can then be passed into whatever `multiprocessing` function you are trying to use.